# Wordpress Plugin with database for Networks Sites

Tags: wordpress

Ok, So i know how to code a Wordpress widget plugin. But what i want is to create a plugin to display some external links(Like Title and Link) in Footer of websites(Networks Sites). These links are different on each Network site.
So can anyone tell me how can i store those links in database for each Network sites ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to the footer widget, and activate Custom Links, make sure you use the full HTTP address.

Comment: You can also go into footer.php, then find the place that you want to put your link, then post the link using HTML

Comment: Man i don't want to add HTML in footer.I want to create a plugin with database.

Comment: Please look through other posts on creating a database. Your question is far too vague and covers too many topics. I'd suggest start by searching for instructions on how to create a database in MySql, and then how to connect to it in PHP. Once you know those things you should easily be able to connect your widget.

Comment: My question is how can i create a database with plugin that will work on each network site with different values.

Comment: How many network sites do you have? Are they different domains?

Comment: I have 7 different network sites and they are on same domain and same database.